# RowFilter In and Not In List<String> fails to return rows C#

Tags: c#, rowfilter

Within my code, I am including 2 checkboxes which filters the product information within a table whether its on order or not. The products that are on order are stored in a List. The code I use is shown below:-

```
// productsOnOrder is updated at the beginning of this method based off data stored on a MySQL database.
if (chkShowOrdered.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
{
    tempTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("StockNo IN ({0})", String.Join(",", productsOnOrder));
    tempTable = tempTable.DefaultView.ToTable();
}
else if (chkNotOrdered.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
{
    tempTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("StockNo NOT IN ({0})", String.Join(",", productsOnOrder));
    tempTable = tempTable.DefaultView.ToTable();
}
```

The issue is, even though there are products on order, the table is always blank when you try and filter them. As well as this, all products appear when you try to filter by not ordered. I have converted the values within the table and within the List to uppercase to ensure the values are in the same format.

How come the RowFilter isn't producing the desired results?

Comment: Is `productsOnOrder` a bunch of `string` values?

Comment: Yes they are all string values stored in a List<String>

Comment: Are you sure you have to use `StockNo`? Maybe it should be something like `ProductNo`? Second thing is you override `tempTable` so it will be completely new object and databinding to old object will not work. If values are strings not numbers than you have to escame them (put in quotes)

Comment: Then you probably need to tell that to the SQL statement. Something like: `String.Format("StockNo IN ('{0}')", String.Join("','", productsOnOrder))` -- i.e. put `'` around the values. -- and hope you don't fall victim to SQL injection...

Comment: You don't need this line of code `tempTable = tempTable.DefaultView.ToTable();`. Applying the `RowFilter` should filter the rows in the table

Comment: @Corak It worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As @Corak stated, the reason why it wasn't working was due to the fact the values were not enclosed inside single quotes. Using the code he provided, the issue has now been resolved.